# Ошибка "Call to undefined function mysqli_fetch_all"

Tags: php, mysql, model

Ругается на `mysqli_fetch_all`, когда выложил на хостинг.

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_fetch_all() in /home/admin/models/options_model.php on line 6

```
      function get_options(){
    global $connection;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM options";
    $res = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    if($res){
        return mysqli_fetch_all($res, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Нет модуля `mysqli` для php на хостинге?

Comment: сделай так `while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){

}`

Answer (score 2):

В документации сказано следующее:

> Только для MySQL Native Driver
>
> Доступно только с расширением [mysqlnd](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.mysqlnd.php).

Не уверен что вы хотите сразу забить себе память возвращая все строки в массив, тем более когда логично представить что память у вас ограниченная а выборка с базы это N-число строк. Тут сразу назревает логичное решение вызывать много раз функцию fetch_assoc() в цикле, чтобы каждый последующий 'тик' перезаписывал переменную только одной строкой.

```
while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){ }
```

Гениально не правда ли?)

Comment: Этот ответ можно считать верным. И выхода 2: либо убедить хостера установить mysqlnd, либо читать построчно.

Comment: @P-A Вы абсолютно правы!

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `fetch_assoc` в цикле, либо делайте запросы с помощью PDO.

Comment: Если бы не было модуля mysqli - то ошибка бы посыпалась еще на строке $res = mysqli_query($connection, $query); , а если еще точнее - то на mysqli_connect. Как ниже верно замечено - дело в драйвере mysql.

Comment: @P-A поправил ответ